# How do I add a new hideshow block to Python mode?

Tags: python, hideshow

I'm using a Python decorator that takes so many arguments it happens to frequently span multiple lines, and so I'd like to configure `hs-minor-mode` to recognize the decorator lines as a hideable block.

Right now my code looks sorta like this:

```
@multiline.decorator(arg1, arg2,
    arg3, arg4,
    arg5, arg6)
def fn():
    pass
```

I want it to look like this after saying `hs-hide-all`:

```
@multiline.decorator(arg1, arg2,...
def fn():...
```

I found the variable `hs-block-start-regexp` and tweaked its value in the buffer from

```
\\s-*\\(?:def\\|class\\)\\>
```

to

```
\\s-*\\(?:\\(?:def\\|class\\)\\>\\|@\\)
```

but I'm not seeing any change in behavior.  What am I missing?